# v-model on dropdown not updating data value in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If i set the initial value on the data property the initial dropdown option is correctly set, but it is not working the other way. If i select a value on the dropdown the data property is not being updated.

```
      <select
        class="form-control"
        name="call_type"
        id="call_type"
        v-model="form.productType"
        >
        <option value="Lead">Lead</option>
        <option value="Opportunity">Opportunity</option>
        <option value="Client">Client</option>
       </select>
```

Data object

```
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
      form: {
        productType: 'Lead',
      }
    };
  },
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code above

Comment: The code works here is a link that can be helpful  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else, i was using a template that was changing my select tags to jQuery Nice Select, and for some reason this was affecting Vue.js.